# Differentiating between pressing key the first time and 2nd and 3rd time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

So I got a program that will start a function by pressing F1 and it will stop it by pressing **F1** again, which will send it back into my ***on_press*** function. How can I tell the difference between 2nd and 3rd time the user presses **F1** so I know if to stop and if to start again (if he stops it and wants to turn it back on, basically 3rd **F1**)

I'm currently adding the `stoploopf2 = 1` and break to stop the loop and go back to the ***on_press*** function:

```
if keyboard.is_pressed('f2'):  # if key 'f2' is pressed 
    print('f2 has been pressed')
    count = 0
    stoploopf2 = 1
    break
```

And checking the following in my *on_press*:

```
if key == Key.f2 and stoploopf2 == 0:
    region = (14,835, 600, 1021)
    get_region(region)
    print('before alert f2 pressed')
    time.sleep(0.1)
    magmafarm(1)
if key == Key.f2 and stoploopf2 == 2:
    stoploopf2 = 0
if key == Key.f2 and stoploopf2 == 1:
    stoploopf2 = stoploopf2 + 1
```

Basically if first time **F2** it will start `magmafarm()`, if f2 is pressed while `magmafarm()` is running it will give the variable `stoploopf2 = 1` thus doing

if key == Key.f2 and stoploopf2 == 1:
stoploopf2 = stoploopf2 + 1

However, for some reason, it sometimes just goes back into `magmafarm()` again as if `stoploopf2 = 0`.

Comment: Isn't it just a toggle?  Can't you just say `onoff = not onoff`?

Comment: it is a toggle that I want but doing true / false values wont work because: assuming you do:
toggle = true
and you press f2 to start since toggle = trueand you stop running it thus changing toggle = false
How can you run it again(without restarting the program) since the if condition only accepts true and wont run if its false.

Comment: You should be careful checking when keys are pressed, sometimes you are looking at current key state when you actually want edge detect (for counting).  this is because each pass through the key check loop may count "still pressed" as "newly pressed" which you don't want.